# Wrong output calculating the power

Tags: java

I've the below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    int n=12;
    double val=(3+Math.sqrt(5));

    double ne=Math.pow(val, n);

    String new2=String.valueOf(ne);
    System.out.println(ne);
    String[] new1=new2.split("\\.");

    if(new1[0].length()>3){
        new1[0]=new1[0].substring(Math.max(new1[0].length() - 4, 0));
         if(new1[0].length()<3){
                new1[0]=("0").concat(new1[0]);
            }
         else{
             new1[0]=new1[0];
         }
    }
    else if(new1[0].length()<2){
        new1[0]=("00").concat(new1[0]);
    }
    else if(new1[0].length()<1){
        new1[0]=("000").concat(new1[0]);
    }


    else if(new1[0].length()<3){
        new1[0]=("0").concat(new1[0]);
    }
    System.out.println(new1[0]);
    }

}
```

here i'm trying to calculate `sum of 3 with root 5 and whole to power of 12`

```
(3+sqrt(5))^12
```

when i do it the result i get is `4.246814719604947E8` but in real the answer is to be `424681471.960494`. please let me know where am i going wrong.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The 1st result is in sientific form. You need a format string to show you the second result

Comment: Ponder on`E8` on 4.246814719604947E8.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=tYYMU7qpO4KTrge9ooDoDw&ved=0CBAQ1S4#q=4.246814719604947E8+%3D) ... :)

Comment: Just want to know how to convert my scientific result to normal result(get all the numbers), i used ` String fin=String.format(new2, "###.#####");`, but i don't see any difference, and also the decimals are limited or predefined(please correct me if i'm wrong). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this 
**System.out.println(String.format("%f", ne));**

Answer (score 2):

It's in the scientific notation.

If you don't want it in this notation, you can try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = Math.pow(3+Math.sqrt(5),12);
    System.out.println(d); //4.246814719604947E8
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d).toPlainString()); //424681471.960494697093963623046875
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, my problem is fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the E8 in your answer? Then the answer is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are getting is correct.

4.246814719604947E8 means 4.246814719604947 times 10^8. If you move the decimal point 8 places to the right you see the answer you expect.